# Post links colouring seems broken on mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, mobile-web

Somewhere during the last hour, in mobile web, all the links to posts were rendered solid black and no distinction is made between pages already visited or not:

[image: Links to sci-fi posts in black font]

These used to be coloured in light or dark blue:

[image: former design as seen on M&TV]

Either it's a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), in which case a fix would be welcome, or it's a feature (it does increase contrast, which may be more accessible?), in which case [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) please bring back some distinction between visited and non-visited pages.

---

Android 5.1.1, Chrome 85.0.

Comment: ah, today we shipped a change that introduced css variables, and that's where we probably broke it. We'll take a look, def not intended.

Comment: Please fix asap. I can no longer distinguish between new and viewed posts.

Comment: Same on Android 10, samsung browser (chromium)

Comment: I'll work on this tomorrow. Sorry for the delay, I was out for most of last week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When we shipped a change to do theming using CSS Variables, we forgot to include those variables on the mobile CSS file.

We've just deployed a fix that solved the issue network-wide. If you see any issues, let us know :)

Comment: The blue color used is way lighter than the previous one (see second screenshot in the question). Is that expected? I find it harder to read, since the contrast between the text and the background has decreased.

Comment: it's using the same color as the site. Is there a reason why this is an issue on the mobile site and not on the regular one?

Comment: Well, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxkcA.png) are the former colours, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjErr.png) are the new ones. I couldn't say why this blue doesn't seem so light on a laptop screen, but on mobile I find it really lacks contrast. I'm curious whether I am the only one to think that way.

Comment: I'm curious as well... let's see if more people chime in. We _could_ update all the colors on the mobile themes network-wide, but if there's a problem with the contrast, I think we should fix that, as it would also affect the responsive view (and we can't tweak the colors of the responsive view without touching the colors on the full site).

Comment: Should we let all that in this comment thread, or should I ask it as a feature-request/discussion for the matter to get more visibility, and therefore likely more input?

Comment: I'd say the latter @Jenayah, especially since this is already marked status-completed.

Comment: that makes sense to me